# mysql query of union and mysql_num_rows

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT tbl_post_upvote.id AS i ,
       COUNT(user_id) AS c
  FROM tbl_post_upvote 
  LEFT JOIN tbl_post ON (tbl_post.id=tbl_post_upvote.post_id)
 WHERE tbl_post.author_id = 3 and is_seen = 0
 UNION
SELECT tbl_post_downvote.id AS i,
       COUNT(user_id)
 FROM tbl_post_downvote 
 LEFT JOIN tbl_post ON (tbl_post.id=tbl_post_downvote.post_id)
WHERE tbl_post.author_id=3 and is_seen=0

   $r_noti = mysql_query($sq_noti);
   $l = mysql_fetch_assoc($r_noti);
   $l_noti = mysql_num_rows($r_noti);

   if ($l['c'] > 0 && $l['i']!=0) { ?>
      <span class="badge">
          <?= $l_noti; ?>
      </span>
   <?php } ?>
```

It displays result 
i value 6 , 0
and c value 1 , 0 respectively.
 i want to remove  0 ,0 row
and result is i value 6 and c value 1 only

Comment: I do not understand the sentences `it displays result i value 6 , 0 and c value 1 , 0 respectively. i want to remove 0 ,0 row and result is i value 6 and c value 1 only`. Could you please describe your current result and the result you want to get?

Comment: i      c
6     1
0     0
and $l_noti gives 2 and i want $l_noti will give 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `GROUP BY i` to your statements.

Please try the following:

```
select tbl_post_upvote.id as i ,count(user_id) as c
from tbl_post_upvote left join
     tbl_post 
    on (tbl_post.id=tbl_post_upvote.post_id)
where tbl_post.author_id=3 and is_seen=0
group by i
union
select tbl_post_downvote.id as i,count(user_id)
from tbl_post_downvote left join
     tbl_post
     on (tbl_post.id=tbl_post_downvote.post_id)
where tbl_post.author_id=3 and is_seen=0
group by i
```

Comment: thanx buddy ... its solve now :)

Comment: @yupokadmin That's great. If your problem is solved, you can mark my answer so that the other users see that the problem is solved ;-)